# CakePHP 1.3: Public User Profile With Routes Setup

Tags: cakephp, routes, profile

All,

I have a CakePHP app I am developing with user accounts and some social interaction and I am looking to allow each user to have a profile and make it public and whatever information the user decides to make available. Currently the user is able to access his/her personal account at http://www.domain.com/account, but I want the user to also have a profile at http://www.domain.com/users/profile/user234.

What is the best approach?

1. Create a `function profile($username)` in my `users_controller.php`?
2. Create a `profiles_controller.php` to handle users profiles?
3. Is there a better way?
4. Or is there a CakePHP Profile Plugin available I can use

Also,

Is it possible to use CakePHP routes to have something like this: `http://user1234.domain.com`?

Thank you for you help!

Comment: Probably a good idea to break this into 2 separate questions.

Comment: I thought it would make more sense to have both related question here, but I can split them up no problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 & 2) Both ways work. I would put it profiles controller because its simply more logical but there is not real guideline for that. Usually you do things in the domain they belong to.

3) Not really.

4) Not for profiles but for the whole user thing http://github.com/cakedc/users But be aware that the profiles part is using a key/value storage for the fields of the profile. But you can simply change that by extending the plugins models and controllers on app level - OOP 4tw! :)

For subdomain routing you need to implement a custom route object. See this ticket related to that topic. http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/2429 Lookup the book.cakephp.org if you need to learn how to create custom routes. See http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html?highlight=router#custom-route-classes for CakePHP 2.0. And see http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1634/Custom-Route-classes for 1.3.

Comment: Thanks. I opted to use my view function as profile. In terms of routing, since I am not sure how to implement this routing class, I will just have something like `http://www.domain.com/profile/user1234`. I will look into subdomains later in my development as it is not on the top of my priority list. Thanks for your tips...